# Extract text after period "." from values in a column in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe as follows:

```
| Category |
------------
| B5050.88
| 5051.90
| B5050.97Q
| 5051.23B
| 5051.78E
| B5050.11
| 5051.09
| Z5052
```

I want to extract the text after the period. For example, from B5050.88, I want only "88"; from 5051.78E, I want only "78E"; for Z50502, it would be nothing as there's no period.

Expected output:

```
| Category | Digits |
---------------------
| B5050.88 | 88  |
| 5051.90  | 90  |
| B5050.97Q| 97Q |
| 5051.23B | 23B |
| 5051.78E | 78E |
| B5050.11 | 11  |
| 5051.09  | 09  |
| Z5052    | -   |
```

I tried using this

```
df['Digits'] = df.Category.str.extract('.(.*)')
```

But I'm not getting the right answer. Using the above, for B5050.88, I'm getting the same B5050.88; for 5051.09, I'm getting NaN. Basically NaN if there's no text.

Comment: This seems to work, but again if there's no text/alphabeticals in the value, I'm getting NaN.

For 5051.09, I'm still getting NaN. How do I make this for values without alphabetical characters as well?

Comment: I think he wants: `df["Category"].str.extract("\.(.*)").fillna(df["Category")` @Chris

Comment: @Chris By nothing I mean there's nothing to extract from "z5052" as there's no period in this value.

Comment: @Chris I added the details about expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
splits = [str(p).split(".") for p in df["Category"]]
df["Digits"] = [p[1] if len(p)>1 else "-" for p in splits]
```

i.e

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["5050.88","5051.90","B5050.97","5051.23B","5051.78E",
"B5050.11","5051.09","Z5052"]})

#df

#   Category
# 0 5050.88
# 1 5051.90
# 2 B5050.97
# 3 5051.23B
# 4 5051.78E
# 5 B5050.11
# 6 5051.09
# 7 Z5052

splits = [str(p).split(".") for p in df["Category"]]
splits

# [['5050', '88'],
 # ['5051', '90'],
 # ['B5050', '97'],
 # ['5051', '23B'],
 # ['5051', '78E'],
 # ['B5050', '11'],
 # ['5051', '09'],
 # ['Z5052']]

df["Digits"] = [p[1] if len(p)>1 else "-" for p in splits]
df

# Category  Digits
# 0 5050.88     88
# 1 5051.90     90
# 2 B5050.97    97
# 3 5051.23B    23B
# 4 5051.78E    78E
# 5 B5050.11    11
# 6 5051.09     09
# 7 Z5052        -
```

not so pretty but it works

EDIT:

Added the "-" instead of NaN and the code snippet

Comment: This isn't working. I get NaN for all the values. Please look at my expected output.

Comment: It is working for me. Just replace "np.nan" with "-" in the comprehension (editted the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df.Category.str.split('[\.]').str[1]

0     88
1     90
2    97Q
3    23B
4    78E
5     11
6     09
7    NaN
```

Alternatively

```
df.Category.str.extract('((?<=[.])(\w+))')
```

Comment: Wouldnt this cast an `IndexError` since it would have length=1 when there is no "." ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your first `.` and do `fillna`:

```
df["Digits"] = df["Category"].astype(str).str.extract("\.(.*)").fillna("-")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Category Digits
0   B5050.88     88
1    5051.90     90
2  B5050.97Q    97Q
3   5051.23B    23B
4   5051.78E    78E
5   B5050.11     11
6    5051.09     09
7      Z5052      -
```

Comment: For "5051.09", I'm getting "-". It's supposed to be "09".

Comment: @f722axzo5d Check my edit. I assume your series' dtype is an `object` where some rows are actually floats. Then you'd have to convert all of them to `str` explicitly using `astype(str)` before you can properly use `.str.`

Answer (score 0):

try out below :

```
df['Category'].apply(lambda x : x.split(".")[-1] if "." in list(x) else "-")
```

check below code
[image]